# what happen when execute mvn install if there dont exist pom

Tags: java, maven

I want to install [pig-maven](https://github.com/apache/pig/tree/maven), I download it and run **mvn install** command, then it tell me an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) on project pig-main: Failed to resolve dependencies for one or more projects in the reactor. Reason: Missing:

[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.hive:hive-exec:jar:core:0.14.0-SNAPSHOT`
```

here is some relevant information in pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.apache.snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jboss.org</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    ...
    <hive.version>0.14.0-SNAPSHOT</hive.version>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <classifier>core</classifier>
     </dependency>
```

in [specified snapshot repository](http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/) I find it has some information of target jar but havent jar and pom. So then what should I do to install **pig**. The relate data as below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to install is the last version on github, it's a snapshot version and uses snapshots dependencies. You may try follow the tutorial of PIG and install a stable version.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to install the development version of the project, however it depends on SNAPSHOT dependencies which are not available on your configured repositories.

Depending on what you really want you can:

- As @grape_mao suggested, install a stable version using the proper guide (on the Github project go to *releases* and use the one you want)
- If you really want to use this development version:

  - Find and configure a repository containing `hive-exec-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT`, the one your are showing does not contain the dependency or
  - Download and install yourself `hive-exec-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` from either [a commit from the source code](https://github.com/apache/hive/commits/release-0.14.0) or a `.jar` file.